# Pontus PAC-7002(B) reset

Tags: audio

My 1996 Alfa Romeo 146ti has a Pontus PAC-7002(B) stereo, probably aftermarket.

It has a removable MP3 player and a built-in CD player. The whole interface seems to be locked, possibly as part of a security feature. The volume control works but none of the buttons operate. I put a CD in which plays automatically but I can't skip tracks or switch to the radio or MP3 player.

I can't find any information on the Internet other than that Pontus was part of Hyundai Autonet. I didn't receive the manual for the stereo with the car.

Has anyone used this stereo or got a manual for it? Any tips on how I might reset it? I've tried unplugging the power harness for a while to no avail.

Comment: Can you provide the stereo serial number?

Answer (score 1):

Since this stereo has the front face which flips down, I'd suggest the connection between it and the stereo is at fault, not that it needs reset. You'd need to check to see where the connection is made and how it is made, then see if there what issues may be there.